# Cross-browser issue with HTML p-element and fieldset-element, bug or intended, how to handle?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

My question is: is this a bug or intended behavior, should I report this on the bugtrackers for the browsers, or simply find a css fix?

Here is a fiddle with the minimum amount of code needed to reproduce this behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/tjVvp/8/

I have tested this in Firefox and Chromium. The issue relies on the combination of the `<p>` element and the `fieldset` css code:

```
fieldset {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

If `<p>` is removed, the issue does not appear. In that case, the page is rendered identical in both Firefox and Chromium.

If the `<p>` element is present, but without the CSS code for the `fieldset` element, both Firefox and Chromium will render the page identically.

They need to be both present at the same time, or the issue does not occur.

If the css code for the `fieldset` element is present, that is when the pages are rendered differently, as can be seen in the fiddle.

It gets even more complicated: the issue only occurs when all 3(margin, padding and border) are set to a value. If you remove one of the declarations, the browsers will render the pages identically. It doesn't matter which combination is left, only when all 3 properties are declared will the difference occur. And then only if the `<p>` element is present.

So, repeating my question from the top of this text: is this a bug or intended behavior, should I report this on the bugtrackers for the browsers, or simply find a css fix?

Comment: This is not a bug. Browsers automatically add some space (margin) before and after each <p> element. The margins can be modified with CSS (with the margin properties).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're referring to might be the default margin of `<p>`. If you inspect the `<p>` tag you can see the margins on either side:

[image]

Also note that the margin on the top is being applied not to `<p>` itself to one of its ancestors, this is called [margin collapsing](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins).

### References

- [CSS 2.1 Spec - Collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins)

Comment: Yes, this seems to be a problem with margin-collapse and how browsers handle it. I've been going over Firefox's bugzilla and I found a link to a test-page made by the W3C CSS workgroup. I made the page in to a fiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/k5j8U/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/k5j8U/1/). Viewing in both Firefox and Chrome shows only Chrome renders as expected. I added `-webkit-margin-collapse: separate`, which is here: [http://jsfiddle.net/k5j8U/](http://jsfiddle.net/k5j8U/) and this makes Chrome render identical to Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, I try it on fiddle and it's working fine.

```
fieldset, p, label {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
}

header {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: red;
}

legend {
    margin: 2px 0px;
    padding:0px 10px 0 0;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Instead of trying to fix it, I looked further in to the issue and made a setup so that you'd get the different behaviors with a minimum amount of code. Turns out this is actually a bug in Firefox's behavior for margin-collapsing.